# Regular expression is invalid: unmatched parentheses

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have `mongodb` as db for my `C#` application.

This is how I am trying to search some collection

```
public async Task<PagedResult<Payer>> Find(FindPayerQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        FilterDefinition<Payer> filter;
            var nameFilter = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Name)
                ? Builders<Payer>.Filter.Empty
                : Builders<Payer>.Filter.Regex(p => p.Name,new BsonRegularExpression($"/.*{ query.Name }.*/ i")); 

            filter = Builders<Payer>.Filter.And(nameFilter);
        }

        var count = await Items.CountDocumentsAsync(filter, new CountOptions(), cancellationToken);
        var cursor = await Items.FindAsync(filter,
            new FindOptions<Payer>
            {
                Skip = ((query.Paging.Page - 1) * query.Paging.PerPage),
                Limit = query.Paging.PerPage
            }, cancellationToken);

        var items = cursor.ToEnumerable().ToArray();
        return new PagedResult<Payer>
        {
            Items = items,
            Page = query.Paging.Page,
            PerPage = query.Paging.PerPage,
            Total = count
        };
    }
```

The above method executes fine when the search string is regular text ex. India,Africa etc.

however, when the user searches with

**text = "India)"**

or

**text = "(Africa"**

this throws the error

> Regular expression is invalid: unmatched parentheses

How can I handle this with MongoDB .NET Driver?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest escaping the expression using the C# regular expressions library (you'll need `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`):

```
string textQuery = query.Name;
string escapedTextQuery = Regex.Escape(textQuery);

var nameFilter = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.Name)
    ? Builders<Payer>.Filter.Empty
    : Builders<Payer>.Filter.Regex(p => p.Name,new BsonRegularExpression($"/.*{escapedTextQuery}.*/ i"));
```

As you can see from [this test](https://rextester.com/MHOAP95004), characters that have special meaning in an expression get escaped: `(` becomes `\(`.